# is there statically typed language with nice lambda support for the JVM?

Tags: jvm-languages

I'd quite like to write some Google App Engine apps, but I'm a c# developer by trade, and as such I like static typing and Linq (or at least extensions + lambdas + predicates, if not query syntax). Is there a language I can use on the JVM that offers these features?

Comment: You could just make your first project writing an MSIL interpreter :)  Then, you'll feel right at home.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://kotlin.jetbrains.org/

Easy to learn, powerful for libs and has full JVM integration.
And yes, its readability is amazing (comparing to Java, Scala, C#)!

Answer (score 4):

Scala: http://www.scala-lang.org/

Actually, Groovy also has optional static typing, so I'll include it as well, but most static-type, uh, types seem to prefer Scala.  Groovy can be found at: http://groovy.codehaus.org/

Answer (score 4):

http://code.google.com/p/stab-language/

Answer (score 2):

Since the Google App engine doesn't even include all the basic Java classes, but is a subset, trying to use anything like Clojure, which is a functional language that compiles to Java, would be very risky.

You may want to just stay in the sandbox provided by Google, even though you will be missing a great deal having gotten used to .NET 3.5 and C#3.

Answer (score 1):

I'd look into Scala, it's a neat language, it's fast typed & functional
Support in Google app engine might not be a stretch. Check out this blog post from the Google team on jvm language support

[Many languages and in the runtime bind them](http://googleappengine.blogspot.com/2009/04/many-languages-and-in-runtime-bind-them.html)